# What is included in MEF 2?

Tags: mef, mef2

I see work is still going on with new features on MEF ([MEF Codeplex site](http://mef.codeplex.com/)) and they are shipping MEF 2 beta releases, however they do not have any decent documentation on what the new features are experimenting/exploring/building?

So, what are the new features (in a little bit of detail please, a sentance or two for each would be great) that are part of MEF 2?

Comment: To the person who marked this as not a question, I would love to hear why? This seems exactly like a question "what are the features?" it is something with a specific set of answers. I have asked for more detail which may make it feel a little off but the core is still a true question.

Answer (score 5):

I know one big feature is support for open generics.  This allows us to import parts that look like this:

```
IRepository<T>
{

}
```

using an import that looks like this

```
[Import(typeof(IRepository<>))]
private IRepository<Users> userRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [preview documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#core)

- Support for generic types.
- Convention-based programming model that enables you to create parts based on naming conventions rather than attributes.
- Multiple scopes.

Comment: WTF?!?  Five years later and there still is no documentation on MEF2?  The link provided just gives an overview of .NET 4.5 features and a link to the old MEF documentation.  Where is the document that tells me how to use the new MEF2?

Comment: @DRAirey1 considering that isn't the question the poster asked, it shouldn't be there. That link is for the question, not you. Here is the documentation for the current version MEF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition(v=vs.110).aspx